# Modifying the Eclipse Debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, softune

I am attempting to modify the eclipse CDT debugger to allow my to step though my code on my FR family Fujitsu board. The board can only be communicated by the SOFTUNE IDE. Fujitsu provides a dll for communicating with with SOFTUNE's debugger.

Making a simple c++ program I was able to get this to work and control the SOFTUNE.

The supplied commands in the .dll are:

```
 Initialize();
 Openproject();
 Build();
 Go();
 Stop();
 TargetFile();
 Reset();
 ReadPC();
 SetBreak();
 GetDebuggerStatus(); 
 GlobalSymbolToAdrress();
 ExpressionToAdrress();
 WriteMemory();
 ReadMemory();
```

The issue I am having is making a plugin to the CDT debugger to pass commands using the dll. Searching the web i can only find making my own debugger, is there an easier way then starting from scratch?